# How to enable raid on Gigabyte G33M-S2L?

Tags: raid

I'd like to set up RAID-1 on my Gigabyte G33M-S2L motherboard and for this reason I purchased two 1T hard drives.

According to SiSoft Sandra the motherboard does support RAID but it is disabled.

I looked everywhere in BIOS even upgraded it to the most recent version but found nothing that would have said "RAID" and the operating system I wish to install sees the two HDDs, not just a RAIDed one.

What could be the problem? Does my motherboard support RAID (as the diagnostic tool claims) or do I need to buy a RAID card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes Motherboards have a special key you need to hit on startup to enter the RAID screen. I know on my EVGA board I have to hit a specific Function key right after the Bios screen to enter RAID configuration.

However I am seeing RAID as `N/A` on their [website here.](http://www.gigabyte.com.tw/Products/Motherboard/Products_ComparisonSheet.aspx?ProductID=2692&ver=)